# Por que Umidade é com I, mas Umedecido é escrito com E?

Tags: ortografia, etimologia

Tanto as palavras Umidade e Umedecido, são derivadas da palavra Úmido. Mas por que elas têm essa grafia diferente, em que *Umidade* se escreve com I, como *Úmido*, mas *Umedecido* não segue a regra?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A variante *humedo* aparece nos séculos XIV e XV no [corpusdoportugues.org](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/) e no [Corpus Informatizado de Textos Portugueses Medievais](http://cipm.fcsh.unl.pt/) (mas a par de *humydo* e já também de *humido*):

> *(15:Oliveira:Gramatica)* bë ou mal disposto pode ser em calidades & feição: calidades como seco ou **humedo**: feição como dëtes grãdes ou desuiados: & tambem muitos falã muito mal:
>   *(14:Vercial:Sacram)* consagraçom por que já he mudado em outra espeçia Ca ho vinho he queëte & **humedo** E ho vynagre he frijo & seco. asi como ho homë morto nom he
>   *(Livro de Montaria, séc. XIV)* E assi pos a estes planetas
>   accidentes e ainda lhes deu calidades, ca deu a Saturno frio, a Jupiter
>   quente e humedo, a Mars seco, o Sol quente, a Venus **humedo** e quente e a Mercurio frio e seco, e a Lua fria e **humeda**, e estas medês calidades pos que aviam os signos.

O cognato castelhano [também é com *e*](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=h%C3%BAmedo).

É desta forma arcaica que, quer o Houaiss, quer o [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/umedecer), dizem vir *humedecer*.

Comment: O que é curioso é que as duas formas parecem coexistir. Creio que o pessoal nesses tempos escrevia como falava, portanto deveriam existir duas pronúncias diferentes.

Answer (score -1):

Úmido não deriva do verbo Umedecer, o que ocorre com Umedecido. Pois Úmido tem o mesmo radical de Umidificar.

Coisas do Português

Assim como Consertar é com S e Certo é com C

Comment: Bem vindo ao PortugueseSE. Quando criar uma resposta para uma pergunta, tente se lembrar sempre de colocar alguma referência para corroborar sua resposta.

Comment: úmido não deriva de facto de umedecer, mas isso só por isso não explica muito. As palavras estão claramente relacionadas, portanto ou humedecer deriva de húmido ou ambos derivam de um étimo comum. E assim a difreença fica ainda por esclarecer.

Comment: Fiz as alterações.